# Why doesn't linqpad display all the columns in a table?

Tags: linqpad

I am using Windows Authentication to connect to a SQL-SERVER database. 
I am using version 4.47.02 of Linqpad.

If you see the attached image, the same table in Sql server has more columns than the columns displayed in Linqpad.

EDIT: The columns that do not get displayed have a [UDT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190232.aspx) for a data type.

How can I get all the columns in linqpad?

[image: sqlserver vs linqpad]

Comment: Not an answer, but it often helps to realize that LINQPad uses entity framework to bind to the underlying MSSQL database. So your question might translate to "why doesn't Entity Framwork display all the columns in my database"?

Comment: What does LinqPad show when you change your language to SQL?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen By default LINQPad does **not** use EF. (See http://www.linqpad.net/howlinqpadworks.aspx)

Comment: @sgmoore When I change the language to SQL in query mode, I get all the columns that are present in the Table. In C# Expression and C# Statement, that I am not able to access the highlighted columns.

Comment: What types are those columns? It may be falling over because it can't resolve them to the equivalent type; I had a quick look in a local SQL db, and don't have any columns with '(not null)' and no type.

Comment: @Chris, it looks like you've hit the nail on the head. They are UNKNOWN TYPE. This table is a part of a schema supplied by the vendor. Now the question is how do I fix this?

Comment: @sgmoore Oops... thanks for pointing out that LINQPad does not necessarily use EF. That definitely makes the problem more interesting. :-)

Comment: That seems tricky, I had a read of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386909%28v=vs.100%29.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781081/linq-to-sql-and-clr-user-defined-types. Not sure I can suggest anything more helpful though =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQPad supports user-defined data type aliases, but not user-defined CLR types. The latter is not easy to deal with, as suggested by the [link that Chris posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781081/linq-to-sql-and-clr-user-defined-types).

Comment: The columns in question are based on a user-defined data type. If I create similar columns on my SQL Server Express edition, I am able to see them. Do I need any kind of privileges on system views for LINQPad to resolve the column data type?

Comment: It's not about privileges. It's because LINQPad relies on LINQ-to-SQL which cannot deal with CLR UDTs.